# Overcome OS Imposed Windows Form Minimum Size Limit by python ctypes

Tags: python, window, ctypes

i am developing a tool by python, 
it need be able to force change windows size to very small, 
but some windows minimum size limited by system

e.g explore window  minimum size is 160 x240

googled, MINMAXINFO defined minimum size of window,

I try change info of MINMAXINFO,

but it does not work, here is my code,

any one can give some advice
to make it works?

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import POINT
class MINMAXINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("ptReserved",      POINT),
                ("ptMaxSize",       POINT),
                ("ptMaxPosition",   POINT),
                ("ptMinTrackSize",  POINT),
                ("ptMaxTrackSize",  POINT),
               ]

lparam = MINMAXINFO()
WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 36
msg=WM_GETMINMAXINFO
hwnd = 334512 #hwnd of test window
def on_getminmaxinfo(hwnd, msg, lparam):
    info = ctypes.cast(lparam, ctypes.POINTER(MINMAXINFO)).contents
    point  = POINT(9, 9)
    info.ptMinTrackSize  = point

ctypes.windll.user32.MoveWindow(334512, 0, 0, 120, 10, 1)
```

Comment: The WM_GETMINMAXINFO message is processed by the Window Procedure of the window, in it's own process. No way that your on_getminmaxinfo function can get called. You must use hooking APIs.

Comment: is there a way to Intercept win system message(WM_GETMINMAXINFO) by python?

Comment: Only way is to inject a DLL in the target process and then subclass the Window Procedure of the targeted window. Don't know if the DLL part is doable with Python. Very *bad* idea to hack `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` of another program anyway. Don't do that. Why would you?